# "Reporting Services" missing from SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration

Tags: installation, reporting-services

Ok, I am getting into SharePoint development for my company and they have an existing installation of SharePoint that runs Reporting Services in "SharePoint integrated mode". Since I'm new to SharePoint I decided to fire up a virtual machine to experiment with (totally trash).

My problem is that I don't see the "Reporting Services" section in SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration, nor do I have the "SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer" web part available to use.

This is what I did:

1. **Installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit** (with all patches installed and .Net framework 3.5 "features")
2. **Installed Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 x64 w/ SP1**
   (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943587)
3. **Installed SQL Server 2008 R2** (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6362)
4. **Installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint Technologies** (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9437)
5. Rebooted the server after all this just in case. :)

Did I install something in an order that is prone for bugs? Is there a good step-by-step guide that shows how to do this successfully?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: Did you install SQL Server 2008 R2 or just SQL Server 2008? Did you install the correct version of the Add-in? If you didn't install R2, you will need to patch to SQL Server 2008 SP2.

Comment: @James Love, I did install SQL Server 2008 R2, I failed to note it above (fixed now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a great while of weeping and gnashing of teeth I finally got "Reporting Services" to show up in SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management.

I think the problem was with the version of the **Reporting Services Add-in** I was trying to use. I was trying to use an add-in that was meant for **SQL Server 2008** while I had **SQL Server 2008 R2** installed. Since I couldn't find an add-in for **SQL Server 2008 R2** intended for use with **Windows SharePoint Services 3.0**, just SharePoint 2010 I decided to go back and use **SQL Server 2008** (minus the fancy R2).

So what worked for me was the following:

1. **Install Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit** (with all patches and .Net framework 3.5 "features")
2. **Install SQL Server 2008 64 bit *(NOT R2!)*** (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8850)
3. **Install Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 x64 with Service Pack 2** (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FB41E51-CB03-4B47-B89A-396786492CBA&displaylang=en&amp;clcid=0x409)
4. **Install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP3 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint Technologies** (x64 rsSharePoint.msi) (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27595)
5. **Cross fingers, hope for the best.**